# Disable GPU on certain applications

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I was trying to train some neural network on an Nvidia GPU, but it seems the desktop environment (KDE) is occupying the GPU:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sat Apr 22 09:04:16 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.39                 Driver Version: 375.39                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1295MiB /  2002MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1139    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             681MiB |
|    0      1591    G   kwin_x11                                        50MiB |
|    0      1594    G   /usr/bin/krunner                                13MiB |
|    0      1596    G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                           126MiB |
|    0      2267    G   ...el-token=FF7F1AB0E04D51461A7E5E08B2463625   136MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the python code I was running:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms


transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))

# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
print(' '.join('%5s' % classes[labels[j]] for j in range(4)))


from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()
net.cuda()


import torch.optim as optim
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data

        # wrap them in Variable
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs.cuda()), Variable(labels.cuda())

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.data[0]
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 64, in <module>
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 147, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device_id))
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 118, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 124, in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 147, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device_id))
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 65, in _cuda
    return new_type(self.size()).copy_(self, async)
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (46) : all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable at /b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCStorage.cu:66
  car   cat  bird   dog
```

How can disable those kde related processes from using the GPU, and let them use Intel graphics instead?

Comment: Support this question... I even have 4GB RAM on the GPU, but the problem stays the same with deep learning (large transformer models). Ubuntu is easily using 1GB or more for other applications. Closing Chrome obviously helps, but around 500-700 will be occupied by /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg and other processes.